# Display objects which come from api in a generic way

Tags: angular, httpclient, response

Is there a nice and kind of 'generic' way to return the `object` from that method:

```
getItems(){
    this.itemService.getAllWithPaging(this.params)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.itemsAndPageableInfo = res;
      });
  }
```

and then display `sub objects` in a nice way?

My `response` looks like:
[image]

and when I try to display `.number` I get error the this is `undefined`. The `itemsAndPageableInfo` is declared like that: `itemsAndPageableInfo : any;`. So this could be `object` etc but I don't define `sub objects` and other properties. Is there a way not to define all of those `sub objects` and diisplay or use the `sub object`, proprty further?

Of course I wouldnt like to define all of this `sub objects` and other properties before displaying it or using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the sub properties in your html by listing out your property

```
{{itemsAndPageableInfo?.totalPages}}
```

you want the safe navigation operator `?` so your code doesnt throw an error while you are waiting for your http request to finish (since itemsAndPageableInfo is undefined on load)

safe navigation operator doc - https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator

Comment: And this the perfect answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try add `*ngIf="itemsAndPageableInfo"` to your html element where you are displaying the data.

Comment: how it will help me? the `itemsAndPageableInfo` is there but I can't displayed their properties

Comment: If  `itemsAndPageableInfo` is not initialized before the DOM is rendered you will get an error that  `itemsAndPageableInfo.anyProperty` is `undefined`.

Comment: Yes I know, so how to prevent it?

Comment: @bielas Andresson is saying you can add an `*ngIf="itemsAndPageableInfo"` to an element that wraps `{{itemsAndPageableInfo.anyProperty}}` (for example `<span *ngIf="itemsAndPageableInfo">{{itemsAndPageableInfo.anyProperty}}</span>`), this way the sub-property won't try to render until itemsAndPageableInfo is defined/loaded. This is another common technique to avoid these types of error. In the doc that I posted, below the safe navigation operator, you can see this implementation.